# Arrowhead does not show up in svg

Tags: svg

I have the following svg, with an arrow. For some reason, it does not show up in Firefox.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->

<svg
   width="210mm"
   height="297mm"
   viewBox="0 0 210 297"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg5"
   inkscape:version="1.1 (1:1.1+202105261517+ce6663b3b7)"
   sodipodi:docname="test.svg"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <sodipodi:namedview
     id="namedview7"
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1.0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
     inkscape:pagecheckerboard="0"
     inkscape:document-units="mm"
     showgrid="false"
     inkscape:zoom="0.92648709"
     inkscape:cx="382.08843"
     inkscape:cy="460.88068"
     inkscape:window-width="1920"
     inkscape:window-height="1143"
     inkscape:window-x="0"
     inkscape:window-y="0"
     inkscape:window-maximized="1"
     inkscape:current-layer="layer1" />
  <defs
     id="defs2">
    <marker
       style="overflow:visible;"
       id="Arrow2Lend"
       refX="0.0"
       refY="0.0"
       orient="auto"
       inkscape:stockid="Arrow2Lend"
       inkscape:isstock="true">
      <path
         transform="scale(1.1) rotate(180) translate(1,0)"
         d="M 8.7185878,4.0337352 L -2.2072895,0.016013256 L 8.7185884,-4.0017078 C 6.9730900,-1.6296469 6.9831476,1.6157441 8.7185878,4.0337352 z "
         style="fill-rule:evenodd;fill:context-stroke;stroke-width:0.62500000;stroke-linejoin:round;"
         id="path899" />
    </marker>
    <marker
       style="overflow:visible"
       id="Arrow1Lstart"
       refX="0.0"
       refY="0.0"
       orient="auto"
       inkscape:stockid="Arrow1Lstart"
       inkscape:isstock="true">
      <path
         transform="scale(0.8) translate(12.5,0)"
         style="fill-rule:evenodd;fill:context-stroke;stroke:context-stroke;stroke-width:1.0pt"
         d="M 0.0,0.0 L 5.0,-5.0 L -12.5,0.0 L 5.0,5.0 L 0.0,0.0 z "
         id="path878" />
    </marker>
  </defs>
  <g
     inkscape:label="Lager 1"
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer1">
    <path
       style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.264583px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1;marker-end:url(#Arrow2Lend)"
       d="M 33.740293,27.950213 102.27875,62.019309 49.732599,111.80037"
       id="path876" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Is the SVG bad (bug in inkscape), or is there a problem with Firefox?

Embedding using img or viewing the file directly has no impact on the result.

On Firefox 91.0.2

Comment: The issue seems to be fill: context-stroke -> if you delete that, it shows up in Firefox

Comment: @MichaelMullany still why it is behaving differently in Firefox is not answered. If this is an issue in Firefox and the SVG is in the standards or vice versa,

Comment: The `context-stroke` and `context-fill` properties are flagged as "Candidate Recommendation" in the [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/fill#specifications). I assume this means they haven't yet been implemented in Firefox. If you replace `fill:context-stroke` with `fill:#000`, the problem should go away (although all your arrowheads will be black regardless of the line colour).

Comment: Context-stroke seems to be an SVG2 feature. It's not in SVG 1.1 and the browsers are implementing different parts of SVG2 at different rates. FWIW - "Candidate Recommendation" status means it's considered stable enough for browsers to implement.

Comment: I think we have a valid answer in the comments

Answer (score 3):

As @MichaelMullany has pointed out:

If you delete `fill:context-stroke` from the `style` string, or replace it by `fill:#000` (or using the hex code for your color of choice), Firefox should be able to display the arrowhead correctly.